# Non-convex support of a matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization

I have an optimization problem in which the variable to optimize is, among others, a matrix $S$. However, I have the constraint that the support of $S$ (i.e., where it is non-zero) is fixed (say, $S_f$):

$$\mbox{supp} (S)=S_f$$

$S_f$  is a $N$x$N$ matrix with $1$ or $0$ in the $(i,j)$ entry if that entry has to be considered or not in the optimization problem. That is, the optimization problem has to ''fill'' the non-zero entries in an optimal way, provided the support in which the matrix is different from $0$.
However this constraint (should) make the optimization problem not convex, due to the support term.
How can I figure the motivation behind the non-convexity ? (Both through intuition and a proof). And the term support, how is formally defined? I see that there exists the support of a function, but not relative to an element.

Thank you.

Comment: So, $S_f$ is a set of pairs $(i,j)$ for which the $(i,j)$-th entry is nonzero?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $S_f$ is a $N$x$N$ matrix with $1$ or $0$ in the $(i,j)$ entry if that entry has to be considered or not in the optimization problem. That is, the optimization problem has to ''fill'' the non-zero entries in an optimal way, provided the support in which the matrix is different from $0$.

Comment: Some would call it "sparsity pattern".

Comment: Build basis matrices of the form $e_i e_j^\top$ and write the matrix along the lines of $\sum_{i,j} x_{ij} e_i e_j^\top$. Then find the $x_{ij}$.

Comment: So I can write as constraint $S= \sum_{i,j} x_{ij} e_i e_j^T$ ? Having the matrix with the sparsity pattern fixed, makes the set non-convex?

Comment: $\sum_{i,j} x_{ij} e_i e_j^\top$ is a vector space and, thus, convex. You can also start with matrix $X$ and then have constraints $x_{ij} = 0$ until you have the sparsity pattern you want. But linear equality constraints are convex. I do not understand your question.

Comment: I have a minimization fitting problem of a function where one term is $\sum_{k} h_k S^{k}$, where $S$ is the matrix which I know the sparsity pattern and $h_k$ are some coefficients. I have to minimize w.r.t. $h,S$. So the problem should be non convex. If I fix $S$, then the objective function is convex because is linear in $h$, but if I fix $h$ the problem is not convex on $S$ due to the exponential right?

Comment: Calling it non-convex sounds deceiving to me. $S$ makes it a combinatorial optimization problem. In compressed sensing, say, one can use linear programming to "solve" a combinatorial problem, but that is a very special problem. However, you are not attempting to maximize sparsity, are you?

Comment: No I am not maximizing sparsity. But I have the constraint on the exact sparse positions, where that entry has to be optimized. But when I have $S^{k}$, I don't think the problem remains convex. Moreover you say that $S$ makes it combinatoric: this is true, but the possible values of the entries are infinities (even if I have a box constraint on the value). Am I right?

Comment: I still do not understand your problem. Edit your question. State the problem mathematically, unambiguously. State what is given and what the goal is. The more English you write, the worse.